# Get Drupal core search results via jsonapi

Tags: search, 9

I am using the jsonapi module to get node content for specific bundles for a mobile app and i am familiar with the filter, include and sorting concepts of the jsonapi.

Now i want to get search results from the drupal core search via jsonapi, but i am only able to get the search_pages (`/search_page/search_page/`) itself.

Is it possible to get core search results for a given search key via jsonapi?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi_search_api

Comment: I think that module is for the search_api module, i am using the core search

Comment: Its pretty much advised to use Search API for high functioning / meaningful searches. I don't think I have used core search module since Drupal 6.

Comment: Thank you, I am aware that search_api is the more advanced search. But unfortunately this does not help me answering my question